# Best Interpretation: 過去を消して穴を埋めて作り変えよう。そうだそうしよう。

Tags: grammar, translation

What is the best way to interpret this line from the song "Dark Blue Day" by Straightener?

「過去を消して穴を埋めて作り変えよう　そうだそうしよう」

I know:
過去を消して：Erase the past
穴を埋めて：Fill the hole

I'm not sure how to interpret 作り変えよう and そうだそうしよう.

Any help/insight anyone could give me would be most appreciated! Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

作り変える means [to remake something, or to give it new shape](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E4%BD%9C%E3%82%8A%E5%A4%89%E3%81%88%E3%82%8B&ref=sa). The idea here is to erase one's past and to reshape... oneself, I guess, as a metaphor for living differently heading into the future. To reinvent oneself.

そうだそうしよう is just `そうだ。そうしよう。` connected into one group.

The others have offered some translations for the line but the general meaning is about reinventing yourself while letting go of past mistakes.

Comment: Ah, thank you so much for your help! I was thinking both of those ideas, but I wasn't confident in my understanding of 作り変えよう given my very basic understanding of conjugations thus far... :)

Answer (score 0):

English is not my native language so I cannot help you to decorate it, but

- 過去を消して - Erase the past
- 穴を埋めて - Fill the hole/undo the wrongdoings
- 作り変えよう - Remake, reborn, start all over again
- そうだそうしよう - Right. Good.
  I'll do that.

Comment: Thank you! I like basic interpretations better. :) They're to the point and help me understand the real meaning.

Answer (score 0):

Kevinamadeus has all the components, here's a composition:

```
Bury the past, pave over my sins, and live life anew. Yes, it is this what I must do.
```